# Class to handle all RecyclerView ViewHolder events

Tags: java, android, interface, android-recyclerview, listener

I'd like to handle every `RecyclerView` item touch event in single class.

I have an activity with a `RecyclerView` and respective `Adapter`. The `RecyclerView` click events are separated from swipe events - and that doesn't seem right to me; I'd rather have all the events for this `RecyclerView` handled in one single class.

What should be the best practice to accomplish this? Should I make the `SwipeListener` an inner class for the `Adapter` (that would reduce the need for another class)? Could I join both interfaces  `MyAdapter.OnClickHandler` and `SwipeHelper.SwipeListener` into one single interface? Or could I create a single class, separated from my adapter, that works along with the adapter to manage the `RecyclerView` by its events? In short, I'm just asking what could I do to improve my code by good practices metrics.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements  MyAdapter.OnClickHandler,
            SwipeHelper.SwipeListener {

    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private MyAdapter    mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);

        mRecyclerView   = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_list);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        mdapter = new ItemListAdapter(this);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        fillRecyclerView();
        setListeners();
    }

    public void setListeners() {
        // need to improve
        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallback
                = new ItemSwipeHelper(0,
                                     ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END,
                                     this);

        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback).attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerViewItemList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        // does click stuff to the viewholder
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSwipedLeft(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
       // does swipe left stuff to the viewholder
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSwipedRight(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    // does swipe right stuff to the viewholder
    }
}
```

**SwipeHelper.java**

```
public class SwipeHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    private SwipeListener swipeHelperListener;

    public SwipeHelper(int dragDirections, int swipeDirections, SwipeListener listener) {
        super(dragDirections, swipeDirections);
        this.swipeHelperListener = listener;
    }

    public interface ItemSwipeListener {
        void onItemSwipedLeft(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position);
        void onItemSwipedRight(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
       // code
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.START) {
            swipeHelperListener.onSwipedLeft(viewHolder, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        } else if(direction == ItemTouchHelper.END) {
            swipeHelperListener.onSwipedRight(viewHolder, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Item> mList;
    private final AdapterOnClickHandler mClickHandler;

    public MyAdapter(AdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler) {
        mClickHandler = clickHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Interface that receives onItemClick messages.
     */
    public interface AdapterOnClickHandler {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    /* code for onCreateViewHolder, onBindViewHolder and itemCount abstract methods */


    /* other Adapter methods */ 

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements OnClickListener {

        ViewHolder(View entry) {
            super(entry);

            entry.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View viewHolder) {
            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            mClickHandler.onItemClick(position);
        }
    }
}
```

I've changed some names and oversimplified the code in order to make it easier to analise. Pardon me if there's any object nomenclature issue or missing elements. I believe the core needed to solve this is included.